# get min/max value from active filters

Tags: layer

I'm getting my active filters like this:

```
$filters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
```

When `$filters[0]->debug()` I can tell the information I want, min/max values is saved in there, but I don't know how to access it.

The output looks like this (I deleted some meta information but maintained the original structure)

```
    array(4) {
  ["filter (Amasty_Shopby_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Category)"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["layer (ModifiedLayer_Plugin_Model_Layer)"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["current_category (Mage_Catalog_Model_Category)"]=>
      array(20) {
        ["level"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["children_count"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["is_anchor"]=>
        string(1) "0"
      }
      ["state (Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_State)"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["filters"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["0 (Amasty_Shopby_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Item)"]=>
          string(17) "*** RECURSION ***"
          ["1 (Amasty_Shopby_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Item)"]=>
          array(4) {
            ["filter (Amasty_Shopby_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Decimal)"]=>
            array(4) {
              ["layer (ModifiedLayer_Plugin_Model_Layer)"]=>
              string(17) "*** RECURSION ***"
              ["attribute_model (Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute)"]=>
              array(28) {
                ["entity_type_id"]=>
                string(1) "4"
                ["attribute_code"]=>
                string(10) "laenge_int"
                ["backend_model"]=>
                string(39) "catalog/product_attribute_backend_price"
                ["backend_type"]=>
                string(7) "decimal"
                ["store_label"]=>
                string(6) "Attribute"
              }
              ["max_value"]=>
              string(7) "55.0000"
              ["min_value"]=>
              string(7) "13.0000"
            }
            ["label"]=>
            string(12) "17 - 17"
            ["value"]=>
            string(5) "17-17"
            ["count"]=>
            int(0)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["label"]=>
  string(19) "Label"
  ["value"]=>
  int(354)
  ["count"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

I should mention that I want a solution using magento functions and not some array accesses as far as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is specific to Price filters. The abstract filter doesn't have a minimum and maximum defined, which totally makes sense as filters are more often then not based on a selection of predefined string values.

Numeric filters have the minimum and maximum support built into their concrete classes:

- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Decimal::getMaxValue()` for decimal based attributes
- The price filter is special, it works with a pricing Algorithm and you can look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price::_getCalculatedItemsData` for some details.

Hope this helps you along.